# how to recognize group id and child id in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the adapter to be used in expandableListView. Don't be confused with other `override` methods in not show.

```
class ExpandableListViewAdapter(
            mContext: Context,
            headerList: ArrayList<Contect>,
            childList: HashMap<Contect, ArrayList<Contect>>
) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    ...
}
```

parent Group View:-

```
override fun getGroupView(
                    groupPosition: Int,
                    isExpanded: Boolean,
                    convertView: View?,
                    parent: ViewGroup?
            ): View {
                var rootView: View
                if (convertView == null) {
                    rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(com.example.expandablelistviewtest.R.layout.list_group, parent,
                            false)
        
                } else {
                    rootView = convertView
                }
                val list = mheaderList[groupPosition]
                val headerlevel = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.expandablelistviewtest.R.id.header_titleOne)
                headerlevel.text = list.name
                return rootView
            }
```

child Group View

```
   override fun getChildView(
                    groupPosition: Int,
                    childPosition: Int,
                    isLastChild: Boolean,
                    convertView: View?,
                    parent: ViewGroup?
            ): View {
                var rootView: View
                if (convertView == null) {
                    rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                            com.example.expandablelistviewtest.R.layout.list_item,
                            parent,
                            false)
        
                } else {
                    rootView = convertView
                }
                val list = mchildList[mheaderList[groupPosition]]!![childPosition]
                val headerlevel = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.expandablelistviewtest.R.id.list_titleOne)
                headerlevel.text = list.name
              
                rootView.setOnLongClickListener { it ->
                    it.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
                    return@setOnLongClickListener true
                }
                return rootView
            }
```

So how to find Contect id when on group item chicked

Answer (score 0):

you can use **setOnChildClickListener** to find parend view data and child position by this:-

```
expendableListViewAdapter = ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, mheaderList, mchildList)
        expendableListView!!.setAdapter(expendableListViewAdapter)
        val id =  expendableListView!!.selectedId
        // Listview on child click listener
        expendableListView!!.setOnChildClickListener(OnChildClickListener { parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id ->
            val data = "($id)parent Address:" + mheaderList[groupPosition].multiAddress + "\n child: " +
                    mchildList[mheaderList[groupPosition]]!![childPosition].multiAddress
            showToast(data)
            false
        })
```